# React Functional Component, Redux and Loading Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, initialization, react-functional-component

I am currently trying to pick up functional react and am having a tough time figuring out the appropriate way to load data from an API on page load. I am using react, redux and thunks. I have modified the project that i created from [this course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/react-redux-react-router-es6/table-of-contents). My code currently looks like this

**store.js**

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import reduxImmutableStateInvariant from 'redux-immutable-state-invariant';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";


export default function configureStoreDev(initialState){

    const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose; // add support for redux dev tools

    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxImmutableStateInvariant()))
    );
}
```

**authorApi.js**

```
import { handleResponse, handleError } from "./apiUtils";
const baseUrl = process.env.API_URL + "/authors/";

export function getAuthors() {
  return fetch(baseUrl)
    .then(handleResponse)
    .catch(handleError);
}
```

**authorActions.js**

```
import * as actionTypes from "./actionTypes";
import * as authorApi from "../../api/authorApi";
import {apiCallError, beginApiCall} from "./apiStatusAction";


export function loadAuthorsSuccess(authors){
    return {type: actionTypes.LOAD_AUTHORS_SUCCESS, authors: authors};
}

export function loadAuthors(){
    return function(dispatch){

        // invoke loader
        dispatch(beginApiCall());

        return authorApi.getAuthors().then(response => {
            dispatch(loadAuthorsSuccess(response.authors));
        }).catch(error => {
            dispatch(apiCallError());
            throw error;
        })
    }
}
```

**authorReducer.js**

```
import * as actionTypes from "../actions/actionTypes";
import initialState from "./initialState";

export default function authorReducer(state = initialState.authors, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case actionTypes.LOAD_AUTHORS_SUCCESS:
            return action.authors;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**AuthorsPage.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import AuthorsList from "./AuthorsList";
import Spinner from "../common/Spinner";

import {loadAuthors} from "../../redux/actions/authorActions";
import {loadCourses} from "../../redux/actions/courseActions";

function AuthorsPage({loadAuthors, deleteAuthor, loadCourses, ...props}) {
    const [authors, setAuthors] = useState([...props.authors]);
    const [courses, setCourses] = useState([...props.courses]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(props.loading);
    const [redirectToAddAuthorPage, setRedirectToAddAuthorPage] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        loadAuthors().catch(error => {
            console.log("Loading authors failed: " + error);
        });
        loadCourses().catch(error => {
            console.log("Loading courses failed: " + error);
        });
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(authors !== props.authors && props.authors.length > 0){
            setAuthors([...props.authors]);
        }
    }, [props.authors]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(props.loading)
    }, [props.loading]);



    return (
        <>
            <h2>Authors</h2>
            {loading === true ? <Spinner/> : (
                <>
                    <button
                        style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
                        className="btn btn-primary add-course"
                        onClick={() => setRedirectToAddAuthorPage(true )}
                    >
                        Add Author
                    </button>
                    <AuthorsList authors={authors}  />
                </>
            )}

        </>
    );
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        authors: state.authors,
        courses: state.courses,
        loading: state.apiCallsInProgress > 0

    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    loadAuthors: loadAuthors,
    loadCourses: loadCourses
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AuthorsPage);
```

The part that i am having trouble with is getting the state for the authors list to set appropriately. I tried setting it after the call to `loadAuthors()` but am not getting the authors list returned in the `.then()` of that call.

The next option was to listen for the author props to change with `useEffect` but this doesn't seem to be the most efficient or correct way of loading the data that i need on the initial load.

I cant seem to find any articles or tutorials detailing the appropriate method to accomplish this from a functional component perspective and would appreciate any guidance or pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The next option was to listen for the author props to change with
>   useEffect but this doesn't seem to be the most efficient or correct
>   way of loading the data that i need on the initial load.

You could render `props.authors` directly without assigning it to `useState`

**Example**

```js
const thunk = ReduxThunk.default;

const { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux;
const { bindActionCreators, combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware } = Redux;
window.redux = Redux;

const initialState = {
  authors: []
};

const getAuthors = () => Promise.resolve(Array(10).fill(0).map((pr, index) => ({id: index, name: `Author ${index + 1}`})))

const loadAuthorsSuccess = (authors) => {
    return {type: 'LOAD_AUTHORS_SUCCESS', authors};
}

const loadAuthors = () => {

    return function(dispatch) {

        return getAuthors().then(authors => {
            dispatch(loadAuthorsSuccess(authors));
        })
    }
}

const authorReducer = (state = initialState.authors, action) => {

  switch(action.type) {
    case 'LOAD_AUTHORS_SUCCESS':
      return action.authors;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const reducer = combineReducers({
authors: authorReducer})
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function mapStateToProps({authors}) {

  return {
      authors
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  loadAuthors
}

const _AuthorsPage = ({loadAuthors, authors}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    loadAuthors()
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Loading authors failed: " + error);
      });
  }, [])
  
  return <div>
    {authors.map(({id, name}) => <div key={id}>{name}</div>)}
  </div>
}

const AuthorsPage = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(_AuthorsPage)

const App = () => {
  
  return <div>
    <AuthorsPage/>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux@4.0.5/dist/redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-redux@latest/dist/react-redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux-thunk/2.3.0/redux-thunk.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```